# Is it worth to convert PNG to WEBP when we can achieve lesser sized PNG from any png converter

Tags: android, apk, webp

I have been thinking of replacing png files in my Android application with Webp images to reduce APK size.

While the results were good, I want to know if i use some png converter/cruncher and am able to reduce size less that what i got for webp images, than should i proceed with using webp images ?

Original PNG size - A KB

After converting to Webp - B KB

Using some good PNG converter/cruncher(PNG to PNG) : C KB

If C is less than B , than what are the advantages/disadvantages of choosing webp method ?

What I have done :

Converted PNG to webp using lossless and lossy conversions :

Original PNG - input.png : 4312 KB

i) lossless - cwebp input.png -lossless -o output.webp

```
   size of output.webp - 201 KB
```

ii) lossy at 80 -cwebp -q 80 input.png -o output.webp

```
   size of output.webp - 25 KB
```

Can we achieve more size reduction with any png cruncher ?

Comment: `If C is less than B` ... Then use **C**!

Comment: It depends on your usage. A WebP file may take a lot longer to compress and you will have to do your own testing to see about decompression time. In general, WebP in lossless mode seems to do better that PNG in terms of output file size, but the PNG decoder may be significantly faster when decoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case C less than B then you should not even think about using WebP.
You should use WebP format when you download image from the web - but if you're talking about resources in your APK then go for a good cruncher (in case C less than B).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Expect WebP lossless images to be 27 % smaller than images produced by a lossless PNG cruncher such as ZopfliPNG. BTW, ZopfliPNG and WebP lossless encoder have been built by the same people.

Did you try the -lossless option in cwebp command line? Sometimes converting into lossy can be a lot more data than the lossless gives. Please post you command lines or tool names/tool options for getting better advice.